# Get link from img src using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, getattribute

I have this HTML code:

```
<td class="songType">
    <img src="https://gg1.net/fdksjhfseiugfeh" class="tooltipHTML tpd-hideOnClickOutside" title="" alt="">
</td>
```

and a WebElement sType that refers to that code. I need the link https://gg1.net/fdksjhfseiugfeh

I tried:

```
String linkSongType = 
sType.findElement(By.className("songType")). 
findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAt tribute("src");
```

also

```
String linkSongType = 
sType.findElement(By.className("songType")).findElement(By.className("img 
src")).getText();


String linkSongType = 
sType.findElement(By.className("songType")).getAttribute("img src");
```

and other.. but nothing worked... I always get null

Comment: can you try String linkSongType = sType.findElement(By.className("tooltipHTML)).getAttribute("src");

Comment: can you provide web-page link?

Comment: this piece of code is working fine - "String linkSongType = 
sType.findElement(By.className("songType")). 
findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAt tribute("src");
" I have tested with your html only

Answer (score 1):

Use Simple Xpath:

```
String yourImageLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='tooltipHTML tpd-hideOnClickOutside']")).getAttribute("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try find use `By.cssSelector`:

```
String linkSongType = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tooltipHTML.tpd-hideOnClickOutside")).getAttribute("src");
```